# How to replicate this theme

Tags: beamer, themes

Which theme and colour should I choose to replicate the attached image?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you give some other clue?

Comment: And there is no attachment in your post. (Or do you mean the picture?)

Comment: This is beamer package, comes in lyx template.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the Copenhague theme with default color modified to replace black by grey:

[image]

You can find more information on: http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/individual/Warsaw-default-default.html

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it Warsaw (my favourite which I use with an other set of colors), characterized by the fading of color in the title line ?
Copenhagen, at contrary has one plain color in the title line.

And probably some white has been added to the default colors.

Cf. [this link](https://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/)

Answer (score 1):

The colours are not from any of the standard colour themes, but you can easily modify an existing theme to use themes colours:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{18,89,169}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{102,102,102}

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=mygray}

\author{name}
\title{text}

\begin{document}

\section{sec 1}

\section{sec2}  
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]